# JPanel technique for Android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Of course and I know that JPanel doesn't exists in Android, but when I was developing with Java Swing I made some panels in one frame and as the user makes his choice, the equivalent panel is shown by setting visible for one and unsetting the other. 
Do you have any idea about how to do this in android?

ANSWERED:

What I was looking for was the FrameLayout that exists as an attribute in the layout xml file and also as a class so at the Java file I created an instance using FindViewById and then set visibility to INVISIBLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each widgit (View) you want to hide should have a visibility property.

This can be set to:

```
Visible
Invisible
Gone
```

Depending on if you want it to take up space when it is invisible.

Comment: thank you for your answer i hoped to there is something more usefull